# Why varnish ban requests not removing/invalidating cached data?

Tags: varnish

I am trying to debug inconsistent behavior with varnish.
I have an application in which when a piece of content is updated a ban request is issued to varnish in order to remove it from cache and invalidate that cache.  The problem is that this works fine just a few times but not in the majority of times although I can see the bans in the varnish log. Just to rephrase, when I save a piece of content, a ban is issued to varnish of the form
`1374003254.031996    75    req.http.host ~ www.example.com && req.url ~ ^(.*)(?<!\d{1})539250(?!\d{1})` where 539250 is the unique content id present in the url.

I logged into the varnish host and check the varnish process. Executing ps -ef |grep varn gives
`root      8889     1  0 15:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -T :8100 -f /etc/varnish/qa.vcl -u varnish -g varnish -h critbit -p http_max_hdr 256 -p thread_pool_min 200 -p thread_pool_max 4000 -p thread_pools 2 -p thread_pool_stack 262144 -p thread_pool_add_delay 2 -p session_linger 100 -p sess_timeout 60 -p listen_depth 4096 -p lru_interval 20 -p ban_lurker_sleep 0.2 -s malloc,1G`

`varnish   8897  8889  0 15:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -T :8100 -f /etc/varnish/qa.vcl -u varnish -g varnish -h critbit -p http_max_hdr 256 -p thread_pool_min 200 -p thread_pool_max 4000 -p thread_pools 2 -p thread_pool_stack 262144 -p thread_pool_add_delay 2 -p session_linger 100 -p sess_timeout 60 -p listen_depth 4096 -p lru_interval 20 -p ban_lurker_sleep 0.2 -s malloc,1G`

Is it Normal to have 2 processes?

then I did an ban.list in the varnish cli:

`1374003254.031996    75    req.http.host ~ example.com && req.url ~ ^(.*)(?<!\d{1})539250(?!\d{1})`
`1374003202.365076   224G   req.http.host ~ example.com && req.url ~ ^(.*)(?<!\d{1})539250(?!\d{1})`
`1374003116.772315    83G   req.http.host ~ example.com && req.url ~ ^(.*)(?<!\d{1})539250(?!\d{1})`
`1374002967.450431   267G   req.http.host ~ example.com && req.url ~ ^(.*)(?<!\d{1})539250(?!\d{1})`
`1374002756.701640   187G   req.http.host ~ example.com && req.url ~ ^(.*)(?<!\d{1})539250(?!\d{1})`

All I want to know if there is somthing wrong causing the ban not remove cached data.

Comment: What's the problem? You're being served content that was cached prior to the ban being issued?

Comment: Yes. at least this is what I suspect. There might be another caching layer. In any case, I jut wanted to verify the varnish is running fine based on the parameters shown in my post. Also, is there a way to verify the ban has been issued from the front end? perhaps a header to see if varnish has indeed banned the object from its cache? it is 'age', am I correct?

Comment: Issuing a ban in varnish doesn't change the caching behavior of your client. If your browser caches a resource and doesn't attempt to revalidate it, or attempts to revalidate it using an etag or last modified date from your backend that doesn't change pre/post ban, you will still see old content. Shift refresh should force the browser to request fresh copies of everything from varnish. Test by using curl to inspect response headers from varnish after a ban, if the Age header is 0 on the first post ban request, varnish reloaded the content from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Your varnish process lines are looking good.

Varnish has a management process which starts (and watches over) a child where all the request handling is done. These are the two processes you are seeing.

If you do a lot of bans, you should consider reading the "Smart bans" chapter in the Varnish book. It will help you keep the list of bans shorter.

https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Cache_invalidation.html#smart-bans